# Angularjs Concatenate $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I like to know if it is possible to concatenate several $scope to make that one.

For example the address of the orginal scope is:

```
$scope.templates.webapp.dc01[0].value
```

I would like the DC01 changes according to my event I tried several thing is it does not work.

I tried in a

```
ng-init="form.template = templates.webapp.{{building}}[0].value"
```

it does not work.

I tried like this also:

```
$scope.test = $scope.templates.webapp + '.' + $scope.building + '[0].value';
ng-init="form.template = test"
```

it does not work well.

---

Plunk demonstrating the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/CaWNeIDHe2nFyEgDABvg?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand what you're trying to accomplish but I suppose you want to do `ng-init="form.template = templates.webapp[building][0].value"`

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tried your syntax. but it does not work. in the console, there is an error 'Incorrect syntax ['

Comment: Can you provide more context? Ideally [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here or on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) or similar site

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/CaWNeIDHe2nFyEgDABvg?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in nesting angular expressions. In provided plunker you're doing:

```
data-ng-options="template.value as template.name for template in templates.webapp.{{building}}"
```

the part `template.value as template.name` is already an expression and `{{building}}` is "nested" in it. Such patterns aren't good idea :)

What you want to do is simply

```
data-ng-options="template.value as template.name for template in templates.webapp[building]"
```

like you would do in plain JS. This way available options in `#s-template` change in respect to selected building.

You can read more about angular expressions [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

---

### Edit

To change selected (default) value upon selecting building you should move the logic from `ng-init` to `testBat` function and call it from controller (instead of doing `$rootScope.building = "Dc01";`). This way selecting building will always select first value from corresponding list.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ggv9DSSLtK3TKvKScZgl?p=preview

Comment: ok thank you for the correction. But this does not correct the default selection when I change the building.

Comment: @marilyn Done! See my answer :)